# Enabling Oracle jdbc driver logs on Websphere 8.5.5

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, websphere, websphere-8

In my application a thread is dead but the dead thread is not updated in my application logs. So i need to check the JDBC logs in websphere 8.5.5. Could you please say how to configure the JDBC logs and view the JDBC logs in Websphere 8.5.5.

I have configured the jdbc logs in websphere 8.5.5 by below things:
Set the following as a Generic JVM Argument on the application server (Servers > Server Types > WebSphere application servers > server_name. Then, in the Server Infrastructure section, click Java and process management > Process definition > Java virtual machine)

```
-Doracle.jdbc.Trace=true 
-Djava.util.logging.configureByLoggingPropertiesFile=true 
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/apps/ibm/was855/lib/ext /oracleLog.properties
```

oracleLog.properties file contents:

```
.level=ALL
oracle.jdbc.level=ALL
oracle.jdbc.driver.level=ALL
oracle.jdbc.pool.level=OFF
oracle.jdbc.util.level=OFF
oracle.sql.level=ALL
oracle.jdbc.handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=ALL
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=jdbc.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count=1
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "JDBC logs" in WebSphere. All of WebSphere's logs are written to `SystemOut.log`, `SystemErr.log`, `native_stdout.log` and `native_stderr.log` for standard output, standard error, native output and native error, respectively.

If you need to issue JDBC-specific logs over and above whatever WebSphere prints by default, you will have to set WebSphere up for JDBC tracing.

A good starting point would be: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rtrb_jdbccomp.html

Comment: I have updated by question with the configurations which I have tried

Comment: I am not sure where you got the instructions, but that doesn't seem right. You should read about JDBC tracing in the WebSphere documentation. I edited my answer.